# Angular2, test directive, undefined-error

Tags: unit-testing, angular, jasmine

I'm trying to test a directive, called `AceDirective` (I'm using the ace-editor).
So first I've build a TestComponent called `MockSearchDirective` which has got this directive:

```
@Component({
    selector: '[testAce]',
    directives: [AceDirective],
    template: '<div ace-editor></div>',
}) class TestAce {}

class MockSearchDirective {
}
```

Now if got my `beforeEach` and `beforeEachProviders` with the needed Injections:

```
beforeEachProviders( () => [
    provide(SearchDirective, {useClass: MockSearchDirective}),
    TestComponentBuilder,
    provide(DataTransportService, {useClass: MockDataTransportService}),
]);

beforeEach( inject( [TestComponentBuilder], (_tcb : TestComponentBuilder) => {
    this.searchDirective = new MockSearchDirective();
    this._dataTransportService = new MockDataTransportService();
    _tcb
       .createAsync(TestAce)
       .then( (fixture : ComponentFixture<TestAce>)=> {
           console.log(fixture);
           this.fixture = fixture;
       });
}));
```

This `console.log` prints the correct fixture containing the Ace-Editor. But, in the specific test:

```
it('Check if editor will be initiated correctly', (done) => {
    console.log(this.fixture);
    // let testAce = this.fixture.componentInstance;
    // let element = this.fixture.nativeElement;//.querySelector('div')
    // let elementRef = this.fixture.elementRef;

    //editor exists
    expect(this.fixture.elementRef).toBeDefined();
    done();
});
```

It fails. The `console.log` says, that `this.fixture` is `undefined`.

I also tried to inject the `TextComponentBuilder` in the test (and not via `beforeEach`):

```
it('Check if editor will be initiated correctly', inject( [TestComponentBuilder], (_tcb : TestComponentBuilder) => {
    _tcb
        .createAsync(TestAce)
        .then( (fixture : ComponentFixture<TestAce>)=> {
            console.log(fixture);
            // let testAce = this.fixture.componentInstance;
            // let element = this.fixture.nativeElement;//.querySelector('div')
            // let elementRef = this.fixture.elementRef;

            //editor exists
            expect(fixture.elementRef).toBeDefined();
        });
}));
```

but then I've got some timeout:

> zone.js:461 Unhandled Promise rejection: 'expect' was used when there was no current spec, this could be because an asynchronous test timed out

Does anyone know this error? And how to deal with it?

Thanks!

**Update**

You still have to use the return-statement, like:

```
beforeEach( inject( [TestComponentBuilder], (_tcb : TestComponentBuilder) => {
    this.searchDirective = new MockSearchDirective();
    this._dataTransportService = new MockDataTransportService();
    return _tcb
        .createAsync(TestAce)
        .then( (fixture : ComponentFixture<TestAce>)=> {
            this.fixture = fixture;
        });
}));
```

Comment: The first test probably (with the `beforeEach`) probably fails because because the process of getting the fixture is async. The `beforeEach` executes, fires off the async creation of `TestAce`, and while waiting for this process to finish starts executing the rest of the code (i.e. the spec) already. The second test I can't fully explain. I do notice that I usually write `return _tcb.createAsync(..,).then(...)`, but I don't think it should matter that much. Do you maybe have a working Plunkr example?

Comment: If tried using `return _tcb.createAsync(..,).then(...)` and it worked - thanks! (Also I thought this was fixed and is not needed anymore..)